# Want to use API without OAuth Authentication

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

I want to use http://api.twitter.com/1/blocks/create.json?screen_name=xxxxxxx (Twitter API) to block particular friends or followers from my account with the use of Twitter & Account Framework in iOS 5,

So what should i do to solve this issue, because i just want to use Twitter account , don't want to use OAuth.

It generate an error like : HTTP/1.1 401 API is secure. Needs security Credentials

Comment: you obviously need OAuth ....

Comment: @Pfitz I downloaded a code from github related to Reverse OAUth authentication, link : https://github.com/seancook/TWiOS5ReverseAuthExample, and then apply my consumer key and consumer secret key then also get the error like : get the error in step 2.

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter API requires OAuth authentication. However, if you're happy with targeting iOS 5 and up you can use the in-built Twitter framework to perform the OAuth calculations on your behalf, which will save you a lot of time. Take a look at the documentation for `TWRequest`:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to put parameters of post requests in the body. This is described in the OAuth tool description under Request query:

This tool is available on the right of every rest API documentation page like [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update) if you are logged in

You can use apigee [console](https://apigee.com/console/twitter) for twitter to test it but you will get the same error unless you include the screen_name parameter in the body